# Is is possible to animate infinite scrolling to a tbody while having a fixed thead?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm working on a little UI to display race finishers. The plan was pull the information into a table to help keep everything aligned nicely.

```
function scrolling() {
  $('#scrollup table').animate({
  top: '-=' + $('#scrollup table tr:last').height()
},
1000,
'linear',
function() {
  var offset = $('#scrollup table tr:last').offset().top;
  console.log(offset);
  if (offset <= 1352) {
    $('#scrollup table').css("top", 0);
    $('#scrollup table tr:last').after($('#scrollup table tr:first').detach());
  }
}
  );}
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval('scrolling()', 1000)
});
```

I am not sure how to keep the thead fixed and maintain the smooth scrolling. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/TJnTN/vdkv6n8b/2/).

Comment: You could have 2 separate tables, one with the thead only and one with the tbody only. Then you can run the animation only on the second table.

Comment: I thought about that but then you would loose the certainty that columns all stay lined up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/vdkv6n8b/3/)**

Just add below style to `thead`

```
thead{
  position:fixed;
  background:gray;
}
```

and in JS while you `detach` `tr` in your animation, just `detach` `tbody`'s `tr`.

```
if (offset <= 1352) {
    $('#scrollup table').css("top", 0);
    $('#scrollup table tr:last').after($('#scrollup table tbody tr:first').detach());
    //tbody here
}
```

Comment: Close....except with the fixed thead the columns no longer lineup with the tbody columns.

Comment: Also the first item is covered is always covered up by the thead when the program starts.